# fail to url encode string

Tags: php, url

When I type this:

```
<form method="post"  action="../Thread/thread.php?threadID=".<?php echo $threadID; ?>."&page=".<?php echo $page; ?> >
```

I get this:

```
http://localhost/PoliticalForum/Thread/thread.php?threadID=
```

how can I encode the variables into the url to avoid such  mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 echo('<form method="post"  action="../Thread/thread.php?threadID=' . $threadID . '&page='  . $page . '">');
```

You had problem with your quotes.

Edit:

```
$url = sprintf("../Thread/thread.php?threadID=%1s&page=%2s",$threadID,$page);
echo('<form method="post"  action="'.$url .'">');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: +1 this way is using all PHP with the HTML inside the quotes, which seems to be what you were originally trying to do but got mixed up with the quotes

Comment: is there a function that can help me pu tall the variables and attach them to the file name?

Answer (score 2):

Problem  with quotes try this one

```
<form method="post"  action="../Thread/thread.php?threadID=<?php echo $threadID; ?>&page=<?php echo $page; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are wrong, try this:

```
<form method="post"  action="../Thread/thread.php?threadID=<?php echo $threadID; ?>&page=<?php echo $page; ?>">
```